# Git BASH - Hook on merge removes line breaks

Tags: bash, git, githooks

I am using a git hook in my `prepare-commit-msg` to automatically prepend branch names to the commit message:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //')
echo "$NAME"' - '$(cat "$1") > "$1"
```

However if I do a git merge, all of the line endings are removed. This causes an issue because git will automatically include lines with comments starting with a `#` which include things like files that were changed.

So what winds up happening during a merge is something like this:

```
my_branch_name - Merge branch 'master' into my_branch_name # Conflicts: # File1.txt # File2.txt # File3.txt
```

Instead of:

```
my_branch_name - Merge branch 'master' into my_branch_name
# Conflicts:
# File1.txt
# File2.txt
# File3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not caused by a merge commit. `$(cat "$1")` always removes the line endings. If you use `git commit` without `-m "some message"`, it also raises the issue.

Try `sed`, to insert the branch name at the beginning of the first line.

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //')
sed -i '1i'$NAME' - ' $1
```